# Can I use ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview() to open front camera at first rather then back camera

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-camera, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

Can I use ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview() to open front camera at first rather then back camera.

```
@Composable
fun PickImage(onImagePicked: (Uri) -> Unit) {

    var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

    val launcher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) {
            it?.let { _ -> imageUri = saveImage(it) }
        }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        imageUri?.let {
            onImagePicked(it)
        }

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {
            launcher.launch()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like there's no official support for that. If you need this, maybe you need implement by your own